# MVC - is it model to view or controller to view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I see numerous sites and articles explaining that the view is updated from the model like the example below [image: mvc] 
however i see a few other examples of MVC architecture showing that the view is updated via the controller [image]

Is this depending on whether you have the @Model into your views? im just wondering why the different versions of MVC, we were taught that it should be the second image.

Comment: first diagram isn't totally correct.. it should be user request -> handled by controller -> manipulate model -> handled by controller -> sent to view. So basically controller is like the middle man which connects model with the view.

Comment: Well first picture gives you a clear flow of how Model - View - Controller. works. But here direct communication between Model & View is shown. The same is  not true for second picture, also except the question ; Is view is related to Model?. Yes it is.

Comment: I thought that too but i after seeing more articles with similar design patterns as the first diagram i began to wonder ha. Unless the second diagram is MVP, P being presenter?

Comment: Looks like your confusion is between "MVC" and "MVVM"

Comment: @RobinVanPersi Regarding "first diagram isn't totally correct" - I note that it is the only diagram currently on the wikipedia for page for MVC, which adds legitimacy to the first diagram.  RobinVanPersi - Are you willing to create an answer to this question and give references as to why you feel the "first diagram isn't totally correct" ?

Comment: @nslntmnx How does presence on a page that anyone can edit add any legitimacy to anything?

Comment: @Balázs On reflection in this case it very little legitimacy is added.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MVC is a loosely defined pattern that gives the architect much discretion over implementation details. This is probably why so many variations of MVC exist.

To my knowledge, it all started with Classic (Original) MVC that separate web application into three parts i.e. Model, View and Controller. The objectives were:

- Achieve loose coupling between Model and View (Observer pattern
  employed to achieve it).
- Encapsulate business logic into Model so that it can be exhaustively
  tested.
- Make View as dumb/thin as possible to lessen the need to test it.

[image: A Standard MVC Interaction]

*The pattern charmed so many that there were several variations (Active Model, Passive Model, Model2). These variations were due to implementations of the pattern in particular frameworks to suit the frameworks' design goals.*

For example, one variation is Model2. Model2 is a web variation (Classic MVC was actually targeted for desktop application) and got popular as "ASP.NET MVC Framework".

[image: The Model2 Interaction as in the ASP.NET MVC Framework]

The key difference between Classic MVC and ASP.NET MVC Framework is, the later provides a neat separation between Model and View i.e. no direct interaction. Rather Controller is responsible to facilitate this communication between Model and View in ASP.NET MVC Framework. This makes ASP.NET MVC Framework web applications a lot easier & efficient to test.

Furthermore, in Model2 there's a sort of loose contract that can be established between the view and the controller. In the ASP.NET MVC Framework, this contract used to be represented by the ViewData container object and nowadays using a ViewModel object.

To avoid confusion, one need to look at the interactions between these three parts (Model, View & Controller) in the MVC pattern implementations currently in use. Also embrace the fact that it is a particular implementation of MVC pattern and one diagram may not be able to describe it completely.